# CSV to XML, delete some rows? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, csv, dom, simplexml

because I have some problems with some XML files which got converted by me from CSV to XML, I just want to delete the data which I don not need directly at the converting progress. So just don't convert them.

Moreover that is much smarter because I do not have to convert/import the data which I want to delete just a few seconds later. So I save time.

This is my converting function:

```
function csvToXML($inputFilename, $outputFilename, $delimiter = ',')
{
  // Open csv to read
  $inputFile = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

  // Get the headers of the file
  $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter);

  // Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  // Add a root node to the document
  $root = $doc->createElement('products');
  $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

  // Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
  while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    $container = $doc->createElement('product');
    foreach ($headers as $i => $header) {
      $child = $doc->createElement($header);
      $child = $container->appendChild($child);
      $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
      $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }

    $root->appendChild($container);
  }

  $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
  $handle = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
  fwrite($handle, $strxml);
}
```

My question now is, I have an array which contains titles. All CSV rows where the title matches my title array should not be converted to XML. But how can I do that? - Also I need to check it by `mb_...` (multi byte) function!

Another options would be to delete the rows where my title array matches a title in a row before converting. Maybe this is smarter? - Or better to check that at the import?

---

***Edit (Add CSV Samples):***
[File 1](http://www.onlinekeystore.com/feed.php?key=GmYAQ4RcndpD3aPkjnWkJf4r&dl)
[File 2](http://www.gameliebe.com/media/pveplus/Gameliebe_Affil_Export.csv)

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Can you provide sample csv file, what the titles array contains and which column in the csv file you are matching on?

Comment: I put a sample CSV file into my question. The array contains a lot of titles which I get from another XML file. So about 1600 titles. And if a title of my CSV file is matching with one in my array, the row should be imported to the new XML file - And yes, my function is working. Only the CSV files which got converted to XML files are broken after that! - The other XML files are correct and where the titles are not matching my array, the node of the XML file is deleted. So it MUST BE the converting from CSV to XML... I don't know why... :(

Comment: As I just commented on your other question, try to boil this down into a [mcve]. If the question is "how do I detect if a title string in this array exists in this other array?" then we don't need to know anything about your XML output, or even your CSV input. What we do need is a small sample of what `$row` will look like, and a small sample of what "my title array" looks like. Breaking down problems into smaller parts is the very essence of structured programming and debugging; you may find that by the time you've broken it down, the answer becomes obvious, and you don't need us at all.